# Create single android widget for multiple application

Tags: android, android-widget

I have develop 3 android applications .Now i want to create a single android widget for all 3 application.I am able to do individual widget for all 3 application.But dont know how to integrate these 3 widget into single widget?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do have to choose one of your applications for the widget to belong to. A widget is simply a special type of BroadcastReceiver, and (like activities) a receiver is a component that must be declared in the manifest of one of your apps. This is how Android sees that you have a widget, and how it knows which app to notify when the widget needs to be redrawn.

You can, however, have your widget use data from all of your applications, and you can have clicks in your widget launch any of your applications. The best way to get data from other applications is to use a ContentProvider, either one backed with a database, or a simple one that returns a small amount of data when requested at a certain URI.

For clicks to launch your other apps, you simply need to define intents that launch your other apps' activities, and configure views in your widget with a PendingIntent that is built using those intents.

Does that make sense? Let me know if you need more explanation.